# How Camel consumes files using multithreading

Tags: multithreading, apache-camel

I have many files in the same directory. These files don't depend on others.

Here is my code:

```
    from("sftp://${sftp.username}:${sftp.password}@${sftp.host}:${sftp.port}/myDirectory?" +
            "readLock=changed&readLockMinAge=10s&autoCreate=true" +
            "&move=finish/$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd}/$simple{file:onlyname}" +
            "&moveFailed=failed/$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd}/$simple{file:onlyname}")
            .threads(5,20)
            .keepAliveTime(20)
            .process(parseTypeProcessor)
            .process(uploadToOSSProcessor)
            .process(saveImgProcessor)
            .end();
```

But it does not using 5 threads to download 5 files from directory **myDirectory** and handle 5 files at the same time.It was using sigle thread to handle files.

It's too slow to consume file using sigle thread.I want to using multithreading to consume these files. Is there any way to do that?
Every help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a JIRA ticket about concurrent downloads. Users that would like this can use the JIRA voting to add more votes for it:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6058

See some of these links

- https://blog.joshdreagan.com/2017/01/05/faster_file_consumption_with_camel/
- https://github.com/joshdreagan/clustered-file-consumer

Comment: Thanks, I have read the article. But it seems to use multiple instances to implements multithreading. Does Camel support using multithreading to download many files from the same directory at the same time in single instance rather than multiple instances?